# Surfing Phrases

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate two phrases to German. 1: "Wipeout Surf Shop" (this is the name of a fake company I thought up for a project) and 2: "hang loose" (generic surfing lingo). I have only gotten so far with Google, and need it to be authentic.

-Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, translation requests are off-topic here, unless it's very specific. Can edit your question and add some context, what you already tried to find a translation, what you found and why these don't seem to fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A surf shop in Germany would be simply called *Surfshop* or *Surf-Shop* or even *Surf Shop*, because we associate the surfing sport with the U.S.

A generic German term for surfing is *Wellenreiten*, so a more artsy surf shop name could be »Wellenreiter«. But I think people in the surfer community would think you desperately tried to avoid English.

Same with the *hang loose* greeting. It's simply not translated. »Bleib locker« or »Bleib geschmeidig« are greetings which match but they aren't specific for the surfing community.

(In general, not even the U.S. reference is needed for "-shop", as there is German *Backshop* which isn't some backyard shop as you may expect but a place which sells bakery items though not being a bakery. The latter are the only ones who are allowed to call their outlets *Bäckerei*.)